# How to compose HTML that acts like the iPhone UI?

Tags: iphone, html, css

I've seen a lot of html that behaves like an iPhone UI. Is there a library for this? Any tutorial/guides in building these html? See screenshot for an example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [ComponentOne iPhone Library](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioiPhone/).  It does exactly what you're looking for.

Now, in all honesty, I ran into a lot of bugs when I worked with it 2 or 3 months ago.  Their components worked fine when you wanted results like what you find in their site, but as soon as I got into dynamically generating data and using AJAX to update fields, I started finding many, many bugs.

In fairness, the tool is new and that was a few months ago.  Its quite possible they have worked out those bugs.  Additionally, I was able to get around them (after much finagling).

Here is the [Live Demo](http://demo.componentone.com/iPhone/ControlExplorer/) you can view from your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's got pretty straightforward [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/iPhoneWebAppHIG/MetricsLayout/MetricsLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007900-CH6-SW1) for the HTML and CSS.